# Is it possible to write ApeV2 tags with FFMPEG in AAC format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I am currently developing an application that allow user to convert formats between each others. To convert the audio files I use ffmpeg.

I have a problem with the aac format that doesn't have any standard metadata format. Searching on the net i've seen that one solution is to write ApeV2 tags (Source: [foobar](http://eolindel.free.fr/foobar/tags.shtml))

I can't find the command line option to send to ffmpeg in order to write Ape tags (I don't know if it's even supported).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg's aac muxer does support APE tags.

Syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in.m4a -c copy -f adts -write_apetag 1 {tags} out.aac
```

where `{tags}` can be

```
-metadata title="TheTitle" -metadata RandomFieldName="Randomvalue"
```

Not sure if Unicode is accepted, or just ASCII.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm. It is strange, I didn't see any mention of that option in the ffmpeg documentation.